# Text not appearing in Fragment view in Android Navigation drawer app

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have an android application I am working on that has a navigation drawer.
I have the drawer contents and a started one a Fragment view.
The code compiles, but the fragment is view empty (no text showing up in the view).

Can some one help me figure out what I did wrong?

Here is my code (from the java class file for the fragment):

```
package com.example.ironmantis7x.infonewmuslim;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


/**
 *
 */
public class TawheedFragment extends Fragment {

    public TawheedFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tawheed, container, false);

        TextView text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txttawheed);
        //text.setText("your text!");

        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.tawheed);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        String entireFile = "";
        try {
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // <--------- place readLine() inside loop
                entireFile += (line + "\n"); // <---------- add each line to entireFile

            }
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //TextView text = null;
        //text.setText(entireFile); // <------- assign entireFile to TextView
        //assert text != null;
        if (text != null) {
            text.setText(entireFile);
        }
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Here is the fragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txttawheed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|top|left"
            android:scrollbars = "vertical"/>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks.

ironmantis7x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not linking the fragment to the main activity correctly. I fixed it.
Thanks for the help guys and letting me post!

ironmantis7x